# What’s the difference between We need someone to take ownership of the issue. and We need someone to take ‘the’ ownership of the issue?

Tags: grammar, articles, nouns, spoken-english, uncountable-nouns

What does having ‘the’ before ownership in the second sentence indicate? When to use ‘the’ if I want to use ‘the’ before ownership?

Comment: **To take ownership of something** is an expression. If you want to insert **the** you would have to give an example of where you think it works

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of compound verbs with *take* + an abstract noun without an article + preposition. For example:

> take notice of
>
> take offence at
>
> take heed of
>
> take care of
>
> take exception to
>
> take time to

When the complement is definite, you might expect the abstract to need *the* in front of it; but in fact these are all idiomatic without *the*.

Some of them can also be used with *the*: you can indeed *take the ownership of* something, and *take the time to* do something; but most of them can't.